# Python PIP failing to work in a background subprocess

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to create a script to install an embedded version of python and I am using get-pip.py to add PIP to it. I have tried to execute this script in a background subprocess by `creationflags=0x00000008` and it fails with an exit code of `1`. I can get it to work without `creationflags` being set but this doesn't work with my application.

I can get it to work without `creationflags` being set but this doesn't work with my application.

```py
proc = subprocess.call([
    os.path.join(base_path, out_dir, 'python.exe'),
    os.path.join(base_path, out_dir, 'get-pip.py')
    ], creationflags=0x00000008)

print(proc)
# outputs 1
```

Comment: What i can get from the above code is you are trying to use DETACHED_PROCESS process, just for sake of it to work can you try this
`proc = subprocess.call([
    os.path.join(base_path, out_dir, 'python.exe'),
    os.path.join(base_path, out_dir, 'get-pip.py')
    ], creationflags=0x00000008 | 0x00000200 )`

I referred to creation flags for window in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags

Comment: Thanks for the insight, unfortunately it did not work **:(** however, I now think this must be due to Python 2's `subproccess` module as it works with Python 3, thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Cheers!!